# wxpython not working properly on Linux Mint

Tags: python, wxpython

So, I have been trying to learn wxpython using the videos on thenewboston.com, but when I run this code all I get is a blank grey window. The size of the window doesn't even change when I change the size in the code! Also the window title, buttons,and panels don't appear its just blank. Im using Linux Mint so I think this may be the cause. Please help me fix this!

```
import wx

class mainApp(wx.Frame):

    def __init_(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title = 'Frame aka Window',size=(800,900))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        buttonExit=wx.Button(panel,label="Quit", pos=(50,50),size=(60,60))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.closebutton,buttonExit)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.closewindow)

    def closebutton(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def closewindow(self,event):
        self.Destroy()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=mainApp(parent=None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misspelt `__init__` `__init_` :)

Comment: OH! I feel so dumb! xD Thanks! LOL